# Loop code with: {x_(n+1) = x_n * r * (1- x_n)}

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, range

Little new here and any help would be appreciated.

I have been tooling around with this code for a while now and I cant seem to wrap my head around it. Im fairly new to python so I dont quite know or remember all the tricks yet/skills.

So the question at hand:

Equation: **{x_(n+1) = x_n * r * (1- x_n)}**

With x_n between (0,1) and r between (0,4).

The goal here is to make a loop function that will gather a value for 'x_n' and 'r' and spit out the iteration 'n' and the current 'x_n+1'; i.e. print(n , x_n+1), at each 'n' step while checking to see if the new value is within 0.0000001 of the old value.

If it settles on a fixed point within 20,000 (0.0000001), print the final 'n' + message. If not then and goes to 20,000 then print another message.

All i have so far is:

```
import math

x_o=float(input("Enter a 'seed' value: "))
r=float(input("Enter an 'r' value: "))
x_a=((x_o + 0) * r * (1-(x_o + 0)))

while x_a != (0.0000001, x_o , 0.0000001):
  for n in range(0,99):
    x_a=((x_o + n) * r * (1-(x_o + n)))
    print(n , x_a)
```

I'm pretty sure this is no where close so any help would be awesome; if you need any more info let me know.

Much appreciated,
Genosphere

Answer (score 2):

You could write a generator function and use it directly in your for loop.  If you need to keep track of the rank of intermediate values you can use enumerate on the generator.

```
def fnIter(fn,x,delta=0.000001):
    while True:
        yield x
        prev,x = x,fn(x)
        if abs(x-prev)<delta:break
```

output:

```
r    = 2
seed = 0.1
for i,Xn in enumerate(fnIter(lambda x:x*r*(1-x),seed)):
    print(i,Xn)

0 0.1
1 0.18000000000000002
2 0.2952
3 0.41611392
4 0.4859262511644672
5 0.49960385918742867
6 0.49999968614491325
7 0.49999999999980305
```

To implement the maximum iteration check you can either add a conditional break in the loop or use zip with a range:

```
maxCount = 20000
n,Xn = max(zip(range(maxCount+1),fnIter(lambda x:x*r*(1-x),seed)))

if n < maxCount:
    print(n,Xn)
else:
    print(Xn,"not converging")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it look when i get a moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exponentially-weighted moving average. Pandas has a function for this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start so far. You might be overthinking it, though.

The following approach just tries to generate this sequence for 20,000 terms. Each time, it checks whether the new value is within 0.0000001 from the previous value. If so, it breaks out of the loop and prints that. If not, it uses python's `for`/`else` construct to print a different value. *Note the different levels of indentation*.

```
x_0 = float(input("enter a 'seed' value: "))
r = float(input("enter an 'r' value: "))

x_m = x_0  # placeholder for 'previous value'
delta = 0.0000001

# Try to calculate 20 thousand terms of this sequence
# We will break out of the loop early if our x_n converges
for _ in range(20000):  
    x_n = x_m * r * (1 - x_m)
    if abs(x_n - x_m) < delta:
        print("Settled on value for x_n: ", x_n)
        break
    else:
        x_m = x_n  # move forward to the next value
else:
  print("x_n did not converge in 20000 terms")
```

Comment: I most likely am, a bad habit of mine. Ill take a look when i get a chance. Appreciate the help so far.